# no language (tuk) support in localization tab, drop-down list of xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I want to localize my app in 3 languages: english, russian and the one that is not in the xcode localization drop-down list. So, what can i do to add the localization of the language that is not in the xcode list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's too late, but thought it would help somebody.

I just created a folder by myself in the project folder, called it tk.lproj. After that, i found that tk (turkmen) language in the drop-down list. Seems like Xcode automatically detects available localizations by scanning the project folder. But i wonder why it hides them out until you create a localization directory for it.